# Laravel 4 Route Paramater use only some on given links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I understand that when you do this in Laravel:

`Route::get('news/read/{year}/{month}/{date}/{title}/{id}', 'PageController@index_page');`

We can use all `{var}` name as parameters in the controller. But how if I only want to use `{id}` and `{title}` instead of all of them in the controller?

This is currently my controller:

```
public function index_page($year=null, $month=date, $date=null, $title=null, $id=null) {

    $plugin_files = $this->addJqueryPlugin(array('unslider'));

    $data['css_files'] = $this->addCSS(array('styles'));
    $data['js_files'] = $this->addJS(array('main'), false);

    $data['css_plugin'] = $plugin_files['css_files'];
    $data['js_plugin'] = $plugin_files['js_files'];

    if (is_null($id)) {
        $data['title'] = 'Homepage';
        $this->layout->content = View::make('page.home', $data);
    }
    else {
        $data['isModal'] = true;
        $data['title'] = ucwords(str_replace("-", " ", $title . '--' . $id));
        $this->layout->content = View::make('page.home', $data);
    }
}
```

I tried putting only `$title` and `$id` but it reads from `{year}` and `{month}` instead. Only solution I can think of is change the order of the route to `news/read/{title}/{id}/{year}/{month}/{date}`, but I'm trying to keep the format like the previous one, is it possible?

Comment: I think the most preferred way is, as you mentioned, changing the order unless you have strong reason not to

Comment: The only strong reason is that the web itself is redesigned, and all the old links uses that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this seems wrong

```
public function index_page($year=null, $month=date, $date=null, $title=null, $id=null)
```

Remember that the order of default parameters must be as last parameters of function - check [PHP Manual example here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-158) for details. I assume you misspelled $month=date for $month='some_default_date_value' ?

Second, answering your questions, you've got at least 2 options here:

A. routing to different methods for different parameter count or order

```
//Routes
//different routes for different params
Route::get('news/read/{year}/{month}/{date}/{title}/{id}', 'PageController@indexFull'); 
Route::get('news/read-id/{id}/{title}', 'PageController@indexByIdAndTitle');
Route::get('news/read-some-more/{month}/{date}/{id}/{title}/{year}', 'PageController@indexByWeirdParamsOrder'); 


//Controller
//different methods for different routes
public function indexByIdAndTitle($id, $title){ return $this->indexFull($id,$title); } 
public function indexFull($id, $title, $year=null, $month=null, $date=null) { ... }
public function indexByWeirdParamsOrder($month, $date, $id, $title, $year) { ... }
```

B. changing the parameters order in route and using optional param / default value

```
//Routes 
Route::get('news/read/{id}/{title}/{year?}/{month?}/{date?}', 'PageController@indexFull'); 

//Controller
public function indexFull($id, $title, $year=null, $month=null, $date=null) { ... }
```

Last but not least, check the [Laravel docs for routing and parameters](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: that is wrong, it should be `null`, I mistakenly edit it when I pasted the code here, I'm trying your solution now

Comment: did it work ? if so, please accept as correct answer so others can also benefit from this solution.

Comment: it DID work when I tweak the code a bit and you gave me some new idea how my controller must be designed, thanks :D